# What does AddEntityFrameworkStores exactly do in AddIdentity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I recently needed to *Generate Email Confirmation Token* for my **.net core 5** app, and while researching I found out I need to register "**`AddIdentity`**" at startup.

```
services.AddIdentity<AuthenticatedUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            }).
            AddEntityFrameworkStores<SchoolDataContext>().
            AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

If I remove '`AddEntityFrameworkStores`' piece, then application builds and starts but crashes at runtime with similar errors like in [following](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18797):

Error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[WebApp1.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: WebApp1.Areas.Identity.Data.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[WebApp1.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'WebApp1.Areas.Identity.Data.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.)'

My question is why we even need to register "`AddEntityFrameworkStores`", I could not found a good documentation or source code implementation of it. Can't we just avoid to use it, or any idea why we need it at first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the [source code.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v2.2.2/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L24)

Basically it adds default Stores: UserStore and RoleStore. If you don't use it you have to provide Stores yourself with AddUserStore and AddRoleStore.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wish exception message should be as descriptive as your comment here :)

Comment: @Laurent English is not my main language. I cant understand meaning of word "Store"  in this, in other explanations, how i know store is shop/magazine, but cant understand relation of "Store" with identity.  Can u please say, what do you mean when you say "Store"?

Comment: @zeroG Store as in a container or database that holds users and roles.