ASP.NET Core - adding roles to identity causes build error
I'm trying to read app roles from the IdentityUser in an ASP.NET Core application.
Per Microsoft's Documentation I've added this to my program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

Now when I build the solution, it fails:

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.

Am I missing something?
This is my program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using MyApp.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))    
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))           
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyAppDevContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();    


Be sure add the AddEntityFrameworkStores like below:
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppDevContext>();

The AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppDevContext> method registers the necessary services for UserManager and RoleManager.
You can also register like below:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppDevContext>();


Detailed explanation refers to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462071/11398810
